# Как правильно обрабатывать ajax запросы в MVC архитектуре?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

В общем, никак не могу понять, какой вариант правильный , по поводу ajax запросов в MVC структуре.  Как всё таки их правильно организовать?

Точка входа на сайт у меня одна, соответственно ajax-запрос мы должны отправлять на `front-controller`. Сам фронт контроллер на данный момент выглядит очень просто:

```
$routes = new \App\Components\Router();
$routes->run();
```

Как я понимаю на первом этапе, нам нужно осуществить проверку ajax запрос к нам пришёл или нет. Соответственно возникает первый вопрос - где это реализовать? В самом фронт контроллере написать проверку и в случае ajax запроса создавать новый объект типа AjaxController и дальнейшую обработку полностью возложить на него? Или же отдать всё это роутеру, где  в методе `run` определять какого типа запрос(или же вообще написать отдельный метод) и продолжить обрабатывать его в роутере?

Окей, допустим, что наш запрос уже обрабатывается, значит в теле запроса мы должны передать имя контроллера, метод и параметры. Соответственно на каждый ajax запрос у меня должен быть отдельный контроллер? Или я создаю лишь один контроллер предназначенный для выполнения только лишь ajax запросов и описываю в нём разные методы?. 
Например, в моём проекте ajax запросы используются для отправки различных форм, и динамической загрузки контента. В каком направлении нужно двигаться? Вот так?

```
/*
*AjaxController
*/
class AjaxController
{
    public function actionGetContent()
    {
        //подгружаем контент
    }

    public function actionSendRegistrationFormData()
    {
        //отправляем данные формы регистрации
    }

    public function actionSendLoginFormData()
    {
        //отправляем данные для логина на сайт
    }

}
```

Или же работу с каждым объектом сайта вынести в отдельный контроллер?

Comment: я честно сказать вообще не понимаю, в чем вы видите разницу между ajax-запросом и обычным. и почему для аякса надо что-то делать по другому.

Comment: А что за фронт-контроллер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контроллер он по этому и называется контроллером, контролирует определенную группу действий. В вашем случае и вообще, используется один AjaxController на который ссылаются ajax запросы.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы вы рассказать чуть поподробнее?
Например, если вы советуете для абсолютно всех ajax запросов использовать один AjaxController, то как всё таки мы в него должны попасть? Непосредственно через фронт-контроллер, или через роутер?